# Asking Where Clause in Include Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, where-clause

I would like to select one image from products images when i call products list. I could not use two where and function in row. my database structure is like below:

Products:
ID
Name

Images:
ID
Name
Status
ProductID

I need only images which has true status.

my function for getting products is same below: (incomplete)

```
Public Function GetProducts() As List(Of LeannModel.Product)

    Dim xList As New List(Of LeannModel.Product)

    Using context As New LeannEntities

        xList = (From w In context.Products.Include("Image").Where(Function(i) i.Images.Where(Function(u) u.ImageBase = True)) Select w).ToList

    End Using


    Return xList

End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use condition on included data. Include always loads all related entities so in your case you can try to revert the query. Query images with condition and include product (where you don't have any condition). Once you have data in the application you can call `ToList` and transform result set to have product with image instead of image with product.